# How to load image with picasso in android for an item before item appears?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I have a recycler view that each item of it has an image that picasso loads that image.

When I scroll the recycler view before picasso loads the image, I show a placeholder but in most of the cases, picasso is slow and placeholder appears.

Note that I load images in onBindViewHolder and I want to load images before in a way that in most of the cases placeholder doesn't appear.

```java
public void onBindViewHolder(...){
    Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is the way `ImageLoading` works in List ..Loading time depends upon network strength and Image Size in bytes ...

Comment: Is there any way to call onBindViewHolder a little soon?

Comment: NO .. There isn't... Also loading Images in Advance can be very Tricky..

Comment: Can you explain or introduce a reference to learn it?

Comment: you may want to try to preload next image from the internet in previous `onBindVIewHolder`

Answer (score 0):

BindViewHolder will not be called for all of your items, In your activity Loop through your all list items and then call your above code.

```
for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++) { // here I assumed that list is an ArrayList having all URLs.
 Picasso.with(context).load(list.get(i).url).into(imageView); // here imageview is an empty Imageview with zero width and height.
}
```

This above code will load all images and save it into cache, and when you'll call in adapter onBindView, it will load images from cache.

Comment: BindViewHolder called for all items. My list size is over than 1000(!) and I'm looking for a way to load images in the cache in a better way.

Comment: Then you can do in the way that write my above code in your OnBindView, and load next 20 images in cache, via loop through the list when any image is loading. So it means every time an image is loaded we will also load next 20 images in cache, I think its a good way.